# How to set php timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I have tried to fix this for hours but without any bigger success. I need this to be working

(I have managed to fix another function (while not using `{}` tag) using a normal php function such as:

```
$mytime = $utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
$utc = strtotime($utc_str); )
```

But it doesn't allow me to set a normal gmdate while inside `{}` tag.

this is what have worked decent but the for format is wrong.

```
{
    var $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d g:i:s A';
}
```

result: `2013-05-17 8:52:38 AM` (I need to have timezone: gmt +01) which makes the time `16:52:38 PM` instead.

What i need is a format working to switch gmt and works with `var $dateFormat = ''`

Edit: the code I'm working on:

```
class Guestbook{

   var $messageDir = 'messages';

   var $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d g:i:s A';   - This is where I need (GTM +01 timezone)
   var $itemsPerPage = 5;
   var $messageList;

   function processGuestbook(){
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $this->insertMessage();
   }

   $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

   $this->displayGuestbook($page);
}
```

Comment: What is a "`{}` tag"?! What is the `var` keyword doing in PHP?

Comment: this is what im working on and need the time format to:   {
   
   var $messageDir = 'messages';
   
   var $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d g:i:s A'; 
   var $itemsPerPage = 5;
   var $messageList;
   
   function processGuestbook(){
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $this->insertMessage();
   }

   $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
   
   $this->displayGuestbook($page);
}

Comment: `var` declares class member variables in php, but it's been deprecated for a while iirc - either way it doesn't look like he's trying to declare a class member variable here

Comment: I have tested many functions, thats one of those which dont work for this project.

Answer (score 3):

[php_date_default_timezone is the incantation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) you're looking for, you can also use the date.timezone .ini setting. In the interest of there being more than one way to skin every cat, you can also use [DateTime::setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) if you're using DateTime objects.

Comment: var $dateFormat = 'php_date_default_timezone Y-m-d g:i:s A';                                                                  results in: p09p_17am31America/Denver_17America/Denverfam000000Friday31_313605America/Denver13620135America/Denver 2013-05-17 9:36:23 AM

Comment: I have already been on php.net the problem is to use the correct function in my case here.  I'm not asking for sources, i need the solution as I will not succeed any better with this.

Comment: @Felix - why would you put a function name inside your format string? That's just silly.  Call the function like you would any other.  There are examples in the link that hd1 provided.

Comment: @Matt LOLZ, i have already tested many combinations. this is the only way to do this on. how would you otheriwse apply the info if you cant define it?

Comment: @Felix - See my answer for clarification.

Comment: @Felix on SO, laziness is a non-starter, we arm you with the information to solve your problem, as I've done, above, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to get the current *local* time in a specific zone, set the zone and use the `date` function

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$s = date("Y-m-d g:i:s A", time());
```

If you want the current *utc* time, then use the `gmdate` function, which will ignore any local time zone setting.

```
$s = gmdate("Y-m-d g:i:s A", time());
```